# Unable to run sshpass command in centOS

Tags: ssh, centos, sshpass

Have work on CentOS release 6.3 (Final) system. And try to ssh another machine using `sshpass` utility like

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@host
```

But it give me error like

```
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

So from error i think that `sshpass` may be not install so have try to install it by `yum install sshpass` and get following log

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.leapswitch.com
 * epel: epel.mirror.net.in
 * extras: mirror.leapswitch.com
 * nux-libreoffice.org-rpms: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirror.leapswitch.com
Setting up Install Process
Package sshpass-1.05-1.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

from above it seems sshpass is already installed.So why it not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if your shell knows the locations of  sshpass

```
which sshpass
```

If it doesnt give any output use find command to find the location of the executable:

```
find / -name sshpass
```

If you find the path,  you can either use the full path of the executable:

```
/path/to/sshnpass
```

Or add the path to the PATH environmental variable, so that your shell can locate it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/
```

Or the issue might be completely different. sshpass might not be able to find some other dependency. "ssh" client might not be installed. Or your syntax might be [wrong](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass):

Comment: Thanks, using `which sshpass` i got path `/usr/bin/sshpass`.so it works but above path is require to export means its default path.

Comment: You might not have the ssh client installed
What is the ouput of "which ssh" ?
If its empty you need to install ssh client.

Comment: output is /usr/bin/ssh. means already installed

Comment: Are you typing the command exactly as you mentioned above? Can you try these alternatives:

sshpass -p 'password' /usr/bin/ssh user@host
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@localhost

Are you using single quotes or double quotes around the password? If your password has special characters, it might force the shell to mistake the arguments.

Comment: yes command is correct but password contain some crazy character so it cause error.

Comment: For testing just give a normal password.If the issue is with the password, login will fail but you will be able to trace the issue.