# How to run SSH Commands from BASH when RSA Key has a Password?

Tags: bash, ssh, passwords, travis-ci, ssh-keys

### Scenario

We have an **RSA Key *with*** a **`password`** that we are *attempting* to use 
to run `SSH` commands on a remote server via a **`BASH` script**. 
We have attempted to pipe the RSA Key's `password` into the SSH command 
using the **`sshpas`** program. e.g:[**`ssh-test.sh`**](https://github.com/nelsonic/hello-world-node-http-server/blob/4bd308a19c5c79d0a413bd30fc6e8007a6c24464/.bin/ssh-test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
# sshpass -e uses the SSHPASS Environment Variable:
sshpass -e ssh -i ./deploy_key root@$132.62.16.142 pwd
```

**Note**: at present this "sample command" is just attempting to print the working directory on the server for "testing", but the idea is that it will run other more *useful* commands via SSH.

When we execute the (above) BASH script it does not *throw* any errors,
it just "hangs" with no output.
e.g:
https://travis-ci.org/nelsonic/hello-world-node-http-server/builds/384010921#L521
[image]

### *Question*

What is the "secret" to using an **RSA Key *with*** a **`password`** for `SSH requests` in a `BASH` script? (*what am I doing wrong...?*)

### *Additional* Context

Our *Quest* is to use the Travis-CI (Online Continuous Integration Service) 
to *deploy* our App to a Centos (or FreeBSD) server. The SSH key is generated by a script that assigns a random "strong" password. We are *aware* that it is *possible* to ["*strip*" the RSA Key password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke) however this is not an option for us.

The RSA Key `password` is *encrypted* (*using the `travis` CLI*) and stored in the `.travis.yml` file which *only* Travis can decrypt and make available as a *secure* environment variable `$SSHPASS` (*used above in the script*).

> *This* question is a *distinct* from other SO questions in that we are using an SSH (RSA) Key *with* a `password` whereas others are using Key *without* a password.
>   We *want* to use SSH (RSA) Key *with* the password (*which is stored as an encrypted environment variable* `SSHPASS`) for security/compliance reasons. 
>   We looked at:

- [How to add SSH Key in Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444891/how-to-add-ssh-key-in-travis-ci)
- [How to put sshpass command inside a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302572/how-to-put-sshpass-command-inside-a-bash-script)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/146201/ssh-hangs-when-executing-command-remotely
- https://serverfault.com/questions/827362/how-to-exit-a-ssh-connection-in-a-bash-script
- [Unable to run sshpass command in centOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375125/unable-to-run-sshpass-command-in-centos)

Comment: Look into using `ssh-agent` instead.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at `ssh-agent` _and_ `passh`. :-)

Comment: @pynexj attempted to use `passh` but still getting the `"Enter passphrase for key"` dialog ... I opened an issue on the `passh` GitHub: https://github.com/clarkwang/passh/issues/2

Comment: u need to specify the password prompt: `passh -P 'Enter passphrase for key .*:' -p ...`