# How to automatically deploy to VPS in Docker from Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy to Docker in my VPS everytime a new commit is made in my project in Gitlab. But I'm having an issue doing that.

I tried to install `sshpass` and then `scp` folder and files. But it's saying:

`sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory`.

The folder and files I'm trying to get from `build` stage, so I dont have to build again my app.

Here's my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: node:9.6.1

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - build/
    - docker-compose.yml
    - Dockerfile
    - nginx.conf

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - dockerize

build-stage:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - CI=false npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
      - docker-compose.yml
      - nginx.conf

test-stage:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - CI=false npm run test

dockerize-stage:
  stage: dockerize
  image: tmaier/docker-compose:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  dependencies:
    - build-stage
  tags:
    - docker  
  script:
    - apk update && apk add sshpass
    - sshpass -V
    - export SSHPASS=$USER_PASS
    - ls -la
    - sshpass -e ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no root@ip:/home mkdir new-super-viva
    - sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r build user@ip:/home/new-folder
    - sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r docker-compose.yml user@ip:/home/new-folder
    - sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r nginx.conf user@ip:/home/new-folder
    - sshpass -e ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no user@ip:/home/new-folder docker-compose up --build
```

Here's the actual output from Gitlab CI:

```
$ sshpass -V
sshpass 1.06
(C) 2006-2011 Lingnu Open Source Consulting Ltd.
(C) 2015-2016 Shachar Shemesh
This program is free software, and can be distributed under the terms of the GPL
See the COPYING file for more information.

Using "assword" as the default password prompt indicator.
$ export SSHPASS=$USER_PASS
$ ls -la
total 912
drwxrwxrwx    7 root     root          4096 Apr  2 13:24 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 Apr  2 13:24 ..
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           327 Apr  2 13:24 .env
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     root          4096 Apr  2 13:24 .git
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           329 Apr  2 13:24 .gitignore
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1251 Apr  2 13:24 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           311 Apr  2 11:57 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          2881 Apr  2 13:24 README.md
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     root          4096 Apr  2 13:20 build
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           340 Apr  2 13:24 build.sh
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           282 Apr  2 11:57 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1385 Apr  2 11:57 nginx.conf
drwxr-xr-x 1191 root     root         36864 Apr  2 13:22 node_modules
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        765929 Apr  2 13:24 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1738 Apr  2 13:24 package.json
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 Apr  2 13:24 public
drwxrwxrwx   10 root     root          4096 Apr  2 13:24 src
$ sshpass -e ssh -o stringhostkeychecking=no user@ip:/home mkdir new-folder
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 3
```

Is there any way that I can copy the `build` folder, `docker-compose.yml` and `nginx.conf` files from `build-stage` to `dockerize-stage` and then pass it with `sshpass`to VPS? It doesnt even working to create folder with `mkdir`. I also tried to create folder manually and then remove this command from `.gitlab-ci.yml` but still the same output.

Just so you know I added that `USER_PASS` in:
`https://gitlab.com/user/project/settings/ci_cd` in environment variables and let it `non-protected`

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375125/unable-to-run-sshpass-command-in-centos>?

Comment: @ksingh yes I just took a look, but its finding the path of sshpass